# Find $E\{(1+X)^{-1}\}$ where $X\sim \operatorname{Poisson} (\lambda)$

Tags: probability

Please show me how to find $E\{(1+X)^{-1}\}$ where $X\sim \operatorname{Poisson} (\lambda)$.

The density function of $X$ is 
$$f(x)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if a r.v. $X$ has range $V$, with $V\subset\Bbb R$, $|V|\le|\Bbb N|$, with density $f_X:V\to\Bbb R$, for every $g:U\to\Bbb R$, where $V\subseteq U\subseteq\Bbb R$ we get that
$$
\Bbb E[g(X)]=\sum_{x\in V}g(x)f_X(x)\;\;.
$$

Now a Poisson r.v. takes value in $\Bbb N$, thus
\begin{align*}
\Bbb E\left[\frac1{1+X}\right]
&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+n}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\\
&=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\\
&=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}-1\right)\\
&=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}\left(e^{\lambda}-1\right)\;\;.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a hint on how to get $\Sigma{\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}}-1$ from $\Sigma{\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}$?

Comment: Write the first terms of each series, and pay attention on where the index start.